# AWS Kubernetes Persistent Volumes EFS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes, amazon-efs

I have deployed EFS file system in AWS EKS cluster after the deployment my storage pod is up and running.

```
kubectl get pod -n storage
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nfs-client-provisioner-968445d79-g8wjr   1/1     Running   0          136m
```

When I'm trying deploy application pod is not not coming up its pending state `0/1` at the same time  PVC is not bounded its pending state.

Here are the logs for after the actual application deployment.

```
I0610 13:26:11.875109       1 controller.go:987] provision "default/logs" class "efs": started
E0610 13:26:11.894816       1 controller.go:1004] provision "default/logs" class "efs": unexpected error getting claim reference: selfLink was empty, can't make reference
```

I'm using k8 version 1.20 could you please some one help me on this.

Comment: SelfLink is disabled in *1.20* and not propagated by Kubernetes.There is a [workaround](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/issues/25#issuecomment-742616668) available, but it doesn't always work.
Please include your manifests in your original post.

Comment: Yes ur right i fixed  that issue now, thanks

Comment: That's great! I turned my comment into an answer. If you think it is useful, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and maybe upvoting, to let community know this is a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes *1.20* stopped propagating `selfLink`.
There is a [workaround](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/issues/25#issuecomment-742616668) available, but it does not always work.

After the lines

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
```

add

```
- --feature-gates=RemoveSelfLink=false
```

then reapply API server configuration

```
kubectl apply -f /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
```

This workaround will not work after version *1.20* (1.21 and up), as `selfLink` will be completely removed.

---

Another solution is to use newer NFS provisioner image:
`gcr.io/k8s-staging-sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.0`

Comment: Yes your right i have use o/k8s-staging-sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.0 image to fix the issue.